# Is there an effort to rewrite the FAQ?

Tags: discussion, faq-discussion

Wax Eagle [recently admitted](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/734/criteria-for-judging-answers-and-which-answer-to-mark-as-accepted/735#735) that the FAQ is out of date. Is there any effort to update it after the recent policy changes? Or are we still waiting for the new policies to be accepted?

Comment: Yeah, that's a good idea!  (That's about as far as we've gotten.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not yet, we were waiting to see what kind of reaction we got from the refocus/quality standards, however we can rewrite the FAQ at any time. If you'd like to propose some initial changes you are welcome to do so.

An important note, we have finally gotten some push back on the quality standards, not sure if its because of the enforcement of them (which has probably been both poor and inconsistent, something we need to work on) or because we need to reevaluate or revise them.

Part of the reason that we haven't updated the FAQ yet was because we were waiting to see what the reaction from the community would be and its been largely positive with a few hiccups. These are things we need to address.

So, 2 options, you can either start a new meta post asking for suggested updates to the FAQ, or just modify this one to be about that.